How can I detect if a reboot happened
I come accross some unexpected auto reboot and no vmcore left.
So I want to catch whenever a kernel reboot happened and who call this.
As I thought before, when I input a reboot command, then the SYSCALL_DEFINE4(reboot) will be invoked and then kernel goes into the function kernel_restart.
But the fact was, when I used kprobe to trace kernel_restart and entered reboot，nothing was caught ---- I've already tested on some other kernel function such as do_sys_open and ksys_umount and they all worked fine so at least my use of kprobe is not wrong.
Now I wonder that is there any other way in kernel to call a reboot?

You could use an auditd rule.

I've tried auditd and found that a systemctl reboot will send signal to kill all other process,so audit can't record...

Fine,I think I find the answer.
It seems that when I enter a reboot,it will send signal to kill all other processes first,even the rsyslogd and systemd-journald,so that's why I can't find any record in journalctl message.
I use kprobe to track __do_sys_open(which should be the syscall of reboot) and add a panic on invoking, and now I can see a rebbot is called in vmcore-dmesg under /var/crash.
Unfortunately, the process in vmcore-dmesg is always reboot even I used a shell scripts to call reboot, and no other threads can be found in vmcore.
But at least now I know that __do_sys_reboot is the way that kernel performs a reboot.
